# How to make two table td elements to be center, next to each other no matter how long or big is their content

Tags: css, html

I have a exercise to make two td elements to be next to each other, no matter how long each of their text/content is? Any ideas?

[image: here you see that it is not int the middle but slightly to the left]

```
<table style="
border:1px solid #2ba6cb;
width:380px;
border-radius:4px;
background-color:transparent;
max-width:768px;
border-collapse:separate";

>
    <tr><td style="border: 1px solid #000000;
            text-align:right;
            vertical-align:middle;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            font-size:15px;
            text-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            text-decoration:none;
            max-width:768px;
            font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            padding:2px;
            float: right;
            ">
            Test 1:
        </td>
        <td style="
        border:1px solid #000000;
        text-align:left;
        vertical-align:center;
        color:#ef5566;
        font-size:15px;
        text-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        max-width:768px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding:2px;
        float: left;
        ">
            Test2ssssss
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Can you add your relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: Unless you're creating an email, you really need to void inline styles, they are a nightmare to maintain. In fact, dont inline styles regardless. [Mailchimp have a handy tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) to do this for your emails so you can use separated styles in your source. Use a separate CSS sheet!

Answer (score 0):

add `CSS` to your table td :

```
td {
   text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The question is how to make the elements centered, not the text.

Answer (score 0):

> Use css **table td{ text-align:center;}**

**See snippet-**

```css
table{
  border-collapse:separate;
  width:400px;
  }
  
table td {
  border:solid 1px #777;
  text-align:center;
 }
```

```html
   

 <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Test1</td>
    <td>Test2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```css
table {
  border:1px solid #2ba6cb;
  width:380px;
  border-radius:4px;
  background-color:transparent;
  max-width:768px;
  border-collapse:separate";
}
td {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:red;
  font-size:15px;
  text-shadow:0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration:none;
  width:50%;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding:2px;
}
td:nth-child(2){
  color:#ef5566;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 1:</td>
    <td>Test2ssssss</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use width:50%;
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/cpdstzx9/ fiddle link, I have updated your code